# display live json data on laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, api

i have live json and i want to display it on laravel blade

my controller code is :

```
public function index()
{
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('link_of_json_file'),true);
    return view('show' , compact('json'));
}
```

and blade code is :

```
        @foreach ($json as $p)
            {{ $p->name }}
          @endforeach
```

and this erros is display:

> (2/2) ErrorException
>
> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   E:\work-landingpage\test\JSON\resources\views\show.blade.php)

Comment: We have no idea what the contents of `link_of_json_file` are. Is it an array of objects?

Comment: You passed true in json_decode second parameter, that mean it's associate array. You can access it like that $p['name'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can remove the "true" to use it as object :

```
 public function index()
{
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('link_of_json_file'));
    return view('show' , compact('json'));
}

@foreach ($json as $p)
        {{ $p->name}}
      @endforeach
```

so if you want to use it as array you can use it like:

```
 @foreach ($json as $p)
        {{ $p['name']}}
      @endforeach
```

Comment: its worked by put "true"
when i delete "true" 
this error msg is displayed
    Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @GhyathDarwish Do not comment on own post when it's not needed. You can simply edit answer!

Comment: @M.ramadan
i edited my answer, please review it to understand what the idea

Comment: if i remove " true" this not worked and displayed Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

if i leave "true" its worked with array $p['name']

Comment: @M.ramadan If you still want to access like this `$p->name` then remove true!

Comment: @Smartpal i removed it but error displayed Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: because , when you put true that is mean you want to use it as array
but when you remove it you will use as object and you use $p->name